# Execute vacuum online

Tags: postgresql, performance, vacuum

I'm new with PostgreSQL, so I hope that this is question is ok.

If I want to execute a vacuum operation (manual or auto).

Is that operation can make problems to end-users or anything with queries or other DML commands?

I'm using version 9.6

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.6.6 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4, 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

Vacuum has a cost in terms of IO on database, but, as in documentation:

> Plain VACUUM (without FULL) simply reclaims space and makes it
>   available for re-use. This form of the command can operate in parallel
>   with normal reading and writing of the table, as an exclusive lock is
>   not obtained.

If you need FULL vacuum, to release space to OS:

> Selects "full" vacuum, which can reclaim more space, but takes much
>   longer and exclusively locks the table.

You can dig deep here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-vacuum.html

Comment: Thanks! so if it's a vacuum without full there is no expected problems, right?

Comment: Correct. Just more load on the system, but no locks.

Comment: No locks, but maybe it can cause performance issues, isn't it?

Comment: Exact. If you run it often, impact is minimal. Just consider your load.